# AngularJS: How do I wait for finishing a asynchronous API using a nested controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First, have a look at below example codes.

```
// parent-controller.js
export default function parentCtrl($scope, MyService) {
    function init() {
        MyService.get().$promise.then(data => $scope.data = data);
    }
}

// child-controller.js
export default function childCtrl($scope) {
    const MY_LIST = ['a', 'b', 'd'];
    function getFoo() {
        if ($scope.data) {
            return MY_LIST.find((el) => el === $scope.data.foo);
        }
    }
    function getBar() {
        if ($scope.data) {
            return MY_LIST.find((el) => el === $scope.data.bar);
        }
    }
}

// my.html
~(snipped)~
<span>{{ getBar() }}</span>
~(snipped)~
```

When I need to check if `$scope.data` is loaded, I do as above. But It seems not a excellent code :/
Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT: Why I need to check this? Because an undefined error will occur without doing that when calling `getBar()` from an embedded code in HTML. I want to run this codes without undefined error not using `if ($scope.data) { ~ }`.

EDIT: After all, I resolved this problem using `ng-if` as below.

```
<div ng-if="data">
<span>{{ getBar() }}</span>
</div>
```